# XLST value of element using XPATH and current attribute name

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to create XSL transformation.
My XML looks like this:

```
<DataRepository>
  <Contents>
    <Content uniqueID="1" name="some.name" ...>
      <Description>Content description</Description>
    </Content>
    ...
  </Contents>
  <Tests>
    <Test>
      <Content uniqueID="1"/>
      <Content uniqueID="2"/>
      <Content uniqueID="N">
    </Test>
    ...
  </Tests>
</DataRepository>
```

In transformed document I want to present test contents by showing content description.
XLS snippet responsible for this is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="DataRepository/Tests/Test">
  <h2><u><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></u></h2>
    <ol>
      <xsl:for-each select="Content">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="//DataRepository/Contents/
                 Content[@uniqueID='{@uniqueID}']/Description"/></li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ol>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

I get empty lines in the output no description shown.
In case I replace `{@uniqueID}` with actual number it works.

Could you please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your source document is not well-formed XML. Could you also give an example of your desired output? It's not clear what you think `{@uniqueID}` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `current()` function to reference the `uniqueID` attribute of the current node:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/DataRepository/Contents/
             Content[@uniqueID=current()/@uniqueID]/Description"/>
```